# Advice on createing index for combination of int. range + int |Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a question on the index for the following table.

```
create table ascertain_telephonenumbersmodel
(

    id            serial                   not null
        constraint ascertain_telephonenumbersmodel_pkey
            primary key,

    abc_or_def    smallint                 not null
        constraint ascertain_telephonenumbersmodel_abc_or_def_check
            check (abc_or_def >= 0),

    numbers_range int4range                not null,

    volume        smallint                 not null
        constraint ascertain_telephonenumbersmodel_volume_check
            check (volume >= 0),

    operator      varchar(50)              not null,

    region        varchar(100)             not null,

    update_date   timestamp with time zone not null,

);
```

The only one type of query this table is dealing with is

```
select
       *
from
     ascertain_telephonenumbersmodel
where
      abc_or_def=`some integer` and numbers_range @> `some integer`
      # example  abc_or_def=900 and numbers_range @> 2685856
```

Question is – what is the best way of creating index for this condition?

DB – PostgreSQL 13

Number of rows ~ 400.000

Current execution time ~ 80-110 msec.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compound gist index.  You will need to use an extension to include the int in the index.

```
create extension btree_gist;
create index on ascertain_telephonenumbersmodel using gist (abc_or_def, numbers_range);
```